# Problems with WCF service. Service failed to invoke

Tags: c#, wcf

I am creating a WCF Service, but i have some problems when i call the service that i have made. Here is the code from the service.

```
public void CreateTradeItemWithExtensions(string gtin, string targetMarketCountryCode, string effectiveDate, string publicationDate, string lastChangedDateTime, string tradeItemUnitDescriptor, string brandName, bool isTradeItemBaseUnit, string descriptionLanguage, string functionalName, string shortDecription, int gPC, string articleNumber, bool isTradeItemAConsumerUnit, bool isTradeItemADespatchUnit, bool isTradeItemAnOrderableUnit, bool isTradeItemAnInvoiceUnit, string startAvailability, bool isPackagingMarkedReturnable, string packagingTypeCode, bool isBarCodeOnPackageVariableMeasureBarCode, decimal netContent, decimal height, decimal grossWeight, decimal width, decimal depth, decimal netWeight, string isDangerousSubstance, string barCodeType, bool isPriceOnPack, string classComplianceRegulationCode, string consumerSafteyInformation, string doesTradeItemHaveAutoReaderTracker, bool isProductCustomizable, string isTradeItemACombinationItem, bool isTradeItemANonFunctioningDisplayUnit, bool isTradeItemRecalled, string primaryDistributionMethodCode, string rFIDTaggedCode, string serialNumberLocationCode, string tradeItemConditionTypeCode, string tradeItemCountryOfAssembly, string tradeItemCountryOfOrigin, string tradeItemOperatingEnvionment, bool isTradeItemAVariableUnit, int tradeItemId)
    {
        //Creating the basic trade item
        CreateTradeBasicItem(barCodeType, classComplianceRegulationCode, consumerSafteyInformation, doesTradeItemHaveAutoReaderTracker, isBarCodeOnPackageVariableMeasureBarCode, isProductCustomizable, isTradeItemACombinationItem, isTradeItemANonFunctioningDisplayUnit, isTradeItemRecalled, primaryDistributionMethodCode, rFIDTaggedCode, serialNumberLocationCode, tradeItemConditionTypeCode, tradeItemCountryOfAssembly, tradeItemCountryOfOrigin, tradeItemOperatingEnvionment, tradeItemUnitDescriptor);

        //Creating a GTIN for a trade item
        CreateTradeItemIdentification(gtin);
        //Adding a GTIN to a trade item
        AddTradeItemIdentificationOnTradeItem(tradeItemId, GetNewestTradeItemIdentificationId());

        //Creating a targetmarket for a trade item
        CreateBasicTargetMarket(targetMarketCountryCode);
        //Adding targetmarket to a trade item
        AddTargetMarketOnTradeItem(GetNewestTargetMarketId(), tradeItemId);

        //Creating basic dates for trade item
        CreateTradeItemDateBasicDates(effectiveDate, publicationDate, lastChangedDateTime, startAvailability);
        //Adding basic dates to a trade item
        AddTradeItemDateInformationsOnTradeItem(tradeItemId, GetNewestTradeItemDateInformationId());

        //Adding brand owner (GLN) on trade item
        AddBrandOwnerOfTradeItemOnTradeItem(1, tradeItemId);

        //Creating Trade item basic description information
        CreateBasicDescription(brandName, shortDecription, functionalName, descriptionLanguage);
        //Adding brand name to a trade item
        AddTradeItemDescriptionInformationOnTradeItem(GetNewestTradeItemDescriptionInformationId(), tradeItemId);

        //Creating basic unit indicator
        CreateTradeItemBasicUnitIndicator(isTradeItemBaseUnit, isTradeItemAConsumerUnit, isTradeItemADespatchUnit, isTradeItemAnOrderableUnit, isTradeItemAnInvoiceUnit, isTradeItemAVariableUnit);
        //Adding basic unit indicator to trade item
        AddTradeItemUnitIndicator(GetNewestTradeItemUnitIndicatorId(), tradeItemId);

        //Creating GPC on trade item
        CreateGPCOnTradeItem(gPC);
        //Adding GPC to trade item
        AddGDSNTradeItemClassificationOnTradeItem(tradeItemId, GetNewestGPCId());

        //Creating Additional Trade Item Identification Value
        CreateSupplierArticleNumber(articleNumber);
        //Adding article number to GPC
        AddClassificationCategoryOnGDSNTradeItemClassification(GetNewestGPCId(), GetNewestClassificationCategoryId());

        //Creating Trade item basic marking
        CreateBasicPackagingMarking(isPackagingMarkedReturnable, isPriceOnPack);
        //Adding trade item basic marking to trade item
        AddPackagingMarkingToTradeItem(tradeItemId, GetNewestTradeItemMarking());

        //Creating Trade item basic packagin type
        CreateBasicPackagingType(packagingTypeCode);
        //Adding Trade item basic packagin item to trade item
        AddPackagingTypeToTradeItem(tradeItemId, GetNewestPackagingTypeId());

        //Creating Trade item basic measurements
        CreateBasicTradeItemMeasurements(depth, height, width, grossWeight, netWeight, netContent);
        //Adding measurements to trade item
        AddTradeItemMeasurementsOnTradeItem(tradeItemId, GetNewestTradeItemMeasurementsId());

        //Creating Basic Dangerous Substance Information 
        CreateBasicDangerousSubstanceInformation(isDangerousSubstance);
        //Adding danger sub to trade item
        AddDangerousSubstanceInformationOnTradeItem(GetNewestDangerousSubstanceInformationId(), tradeItemId);

    }
```

I am using the WCF test clinet to test the service. But when i run the service and invoke it i get this error.

> Failed to invoke the service. Possible causes: The service is offline
>   or inaccessible; the client-side configuration does not match the
>   proxy; the existing proxy is invalid. Refer to the stack trace for
>   more detail. You can try to recover by starting a new proxy, restoring
>   to default configuration, or refreshing the service.

I am kind of new in the "WCF world" so i dont know what to do with this error. I am currently using the auto generated webconfig file that wcf creates. I dont know if that has somthing to do with it. i hope some of you can help with the information that i have given else if you need more to answer i will try and post it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the problem myself. I needed to make a new endpoint's in the webconfig file

```
<services>
      <service name="EPSystem.TradeItemService">
        <endpoint address="ITradeItemService.svc" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="EPSystem.ITradeItemService" />
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
      </service>
    </services>
```

And then i needed to change some of the methods that i was calling. But the basic problem was my endpoint was not working. What i did can be seen above.